# Angular controller calling function twice

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a to-do list app and would like to have it so when a task is there for longer than five seconds the task gets console.logged as expired. But currently the task is getting logged twice.

Template:

```
    <h2>Active</h2>
       <div class = "container">
          <div class="tasks">
             <ul>
                <li ng-repeat= "task in home.tasks" class="task">{{task.task}}{{home.time(task)}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Controller:

```
    (function(){
       function HomeCtrl(Task, $timeout){
          // Tasks
          this.tasks = Task.all;

          //Adding tasks
          this.taskName = null;
          this.addTask = Task.addTask;

          //Expired
          this.time = Task.createdAt;

      }
      angular
          .module('Blocitoff')
          .controller('HomeCtrl', ['Task', '$timeout', HomeCtrl]);
    })();
```

Service:

```
(function(){
    angular
        .module('Blocitoff')
        .factory('Task', ['$firebaseArray', Task])

    function Task($firebaseArray){

        var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("tasks");
        var tasks = $firebaseArray(ref);



        return {
            all: tasks,

            addTask: function(){
                    tasks.$add({ task: this.taskName, timeCreated: (Date.now())}).then(function(ref) {
                      var id = ref.key;
                      console.log("added record with id " + id);
                      tasks.$indexFor(id); // returns location in the array
                    });
               alert(this.taskName + " has been added to active tasks");
            },

            createdAt: function(task){
                if(Date.now() - task.timeCreated > 5000){
                    console.log(task.task + " has expired");
                };
            }
        };

    }

})();
```

Comment: which console message is printed twice?

Comment: You have so many things named `task` that is hard to tell what you are talking about. `{{home.time(task)}}` is a function that will be called multiple times during a digest cycle. Is that the one?

Comment: Yes `{{home.time(task)}}` is the function that is being called multiple times. I only want it to be called once though. What would be the correct way to call it?

Answer (score 0):

`{{home.time(task)}}` binds a watcher to the function and will be executed multiple times during a digest cycle.

From the Docs:

> `$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`
>
> Registers a `listener` callback to be executed whenever the `watchExpression` changes.
>
> - The `watchExpression` is called on every call to [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) and should return the value that will be watched. (watchExpression should not change its value when executed multiple times with the same input because it may be executed multiple times by [$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest). That is, watchExpression should be [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).)
>
> [— AngularJS $rootScope/$scope API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)